# Is there any easy way to mock test solidity on JavaScript?

Tags: solidity, web3js

The simplest way I'm aware of involves opening Test-RPC, making a Web3 instance, a contract, and then using it. That looks more complex than it should. Ideally, we should be able to do something like:

```
sm = require("solc-mock");

var contract = sm.mock(`
  pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
  contract Test {
    function add(uint x, uint y) constant returns (uint) {
      return x + y;
    }
  }
`);

console.log(contract.add("0x1", "0x2")); // output: 0x3
// also contract.add.send for txs
```

Is there any lib that would allow for some mocking as simple as this?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I took a look at the source for remix and noticed they are using a nice library called [ethereumjs-vm](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm) which implements the Ethereum VM in JavaScript. You can use this to mock your tests programatically.

---

**Original Answer:** The closest you can get without touching RPC is the Javascript VM provided by [Remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/). Here's a screenshot I took running your code using just the in-browser VM provided by Remix:

[image: Remix Javascript VM]